# Normality in multiple regression after using first differences

Tags: multiple-regression, normality-assumption, differences, gretl

I´m running multiple regression and after using first differences (as the only method which was succesful with correcting autocorrelation) my model has non-normal reasiduals. As you can see on [image: Histogram]. P-value of Chi-square test is very low. I work with 44 observations (quarterly economic data).

Is this model appropriate even if there is non normality when other conditions (autocorrelation, specification etc) are fulfiled ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you try to transform your data (eg take a log of them) and apply multiple regression on them? this might solve the non normality problem of the residuals, but for more assistance you should give more details.  what are ur data, what model are you applying...

Comment: My dependent variable is inflation and independent variables are interest rate, exchange rate, oil prices, money base and GDP growth and 2 dummy variables. All of my models created had a problem with autocorrelation. So I tried to change function forms, logarithm of dependent variable. This methods weren´t succesfull in correcting autocorrelation but normality was ok. And after that I used first differences and autocorrelation was ok but normality wasn´t. So I don´t know how serious is violating of normality assumption. And if I can use this model.